# Change uuid in dsym file

Tags: ios, crashlytics, dsym

I've been trying to change `uuid` of generated dsym file so that crashlytics can match up crash logs with the `dsym`.

Do you know of any way to do it?

For more context:

- Script uploading the dsym during build failed and I did not notice.
- Bitcode is disabled, therefore there isn't dsym file in itunes connect.
- I am able to build project from exactly the same source code, so symbolicating crash log from the `dsym` should work
- I am still trying to get crash logs from crashlytics but their UI doesn't support it therefore I reached out to their support and then I should be able to symbolicate it locally.

Comment: Why don't you try to find the original dsym files which are contained in the .xcarchive file?

Comment: @KevinLi what if somehow original .xcarchive is lost

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 7):

If you have exact same source code and compiler version, you can build it again and replace new uuid.

To achieve this run `dwarfdump -u <yourapp>.dSYM` to view new uuid. Then open `<yourapp>.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/<yourapp>` with hex editor, locate new uuid and replace with one you needed.

Comment: Just in case anyone is confused how to change UUID with a hex editor, this article is right on the point (I'm not the author): https://mcomisso.me/2016/07/05/edit-dsym-to-fit-a-missing-uuid

Answer (score 5):

Steps to change UUID of a dSYM:

1. Install a MachO viewer/editor. I used this one: https://sourceforge.net/projects/machoview/
2. Use your MachO editor to open the DWARF file located in the dSYM: `XXX.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/<BINARY_NAME>`
3. In the MachO editor, find 'Load Commands -> LC_UUID' then edit the existing UUID to the one you need to match Crashlytics. (see screenshot)
4. Make sure you **save** the change.
5. Use `dwarfdump -u XXX.dSYM` to verify the UUID has been changed successfully.

[image: MachOEditorEditUUID]