# Is it possible to generate dSyms for a build that was already released?

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, dsym, xcode14

Due to XCode 14 deprecating bitcode, I'm no longer able to download the dSyms from App Store Connect to submit to Bugsnag like I used to. Unfortunately I realized this too late, and I've released the latest version of our app in the store.

I had build settings as `DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = dwarf` unfortunately, so I don't have any dSyms locally. Is there some way, with the .xcarchive (which I still have locally), or by rebuilding the same version/build number of the app with `DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = "dwarf-with-dsym"`, to create the dSyms after-the-fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-building with dsyms enabled and then [hex-editing to replace the UUID with the missing one](https://mcomisso.me/2016/07/05/edit-dsym-to-fit-a-missing-uuid) seemed to work for me.

Comment: How did you get the correct UUID to replace with?

Comment: @NicolaiHarbo I got it from Bugsnag

Comment: Thanks for your answer @swrobel - I'm having a hard time finding the UUID in my (online) hex-editor - I can find fractions of it. Which tool did you use to find it? Seems like, in the guide you link to, that he's finding the uuid across horizontal rows, somehow.

Comment: Nevermind - this comment answer me :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/55581049/6198614

Answer (score 0):

Check this article to generate/find dSyms file:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?authuser=0&hl=en&platform=ios

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't find the dSym file in the existing xarchive, and when I re-build, the UUID is different so bugsnag doesn't match it to the existing build